# insert data into the table using jquery and asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, sql-injection

**Default3.aspx**

This is my first page. in which i have two textbox and one submit button, onclick of submit button calling Default4.aspx page, where i have written the data insertion code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#add").click(function() {

var login = $("#loginid").val();
var pass = $("#pass").val();
var dataString = 'login='+ login +'&pass='+pass;

$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> <span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Default4.aspx",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#display").after(html);
//document.getElementById('content').value='';
//document.getElementById('content').focus();
$("#flash").hide();
}
});
 return false;
});
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name="frm_add" id="frm_add">
    <input type="text" name="loginid" id="loginid" />
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" id="add" value="Submit" />
    <div id="flash"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default4.aspx**

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    Dim login, pass As String
        login = Request.QueryString("login")
        pass = Request.QueryString("pass")
        Dim cs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("eExamSolutionConnection").ConnectionString
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(cs)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        ' MsgBox(dob)
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ADMIN_CREDENTIAL VALUES ('" & login & "','" & pass & "')"
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cn.Dispose()
        Response.Write("Added")
     %>
</body>
</html>
```

But, blank row inserted into my table, whenever i'm submitting the value. Need help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and check if everything is alright.

Change the **TYPE** of **JQuery Ajax** to **`GET`** and see if it works or not.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "Default4.aspx",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#display").after(html);
//document.getElementById('content').value='';
//document.getElementById('content').focus();
$("#flash").hide();
```

Comment: thanks !! it works, i have another question, is that possible to put the Default4.aspx code into Default3.aspx code-behind, so that i can save one page for the same process ..??

Comment: @coders : It's better if you separate this two because you are sending data to second page using AJAX

Comment: By the way, @TheJonasPersson's answer is also correct and should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your posted data

```
data: {login: $("#loginid").val(), pass: $("#pass").val()},
```

Then, on your Default4.aspx, grab the data from the form data, not the querystring. `Request.Form("login")`  and `Request.Form("pass")`.